# How do I reset the grub configuration files in /etc/grub.d?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have been changing my grub menu to allow the use of an arch system that I am dual booting, but I managed to get rid of the ubuntu advanced options, so I want to reset the config files in /etc/grub.d to the default ones, but I am not sure what I can do short of reinstalling ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you dorked the grub...it's an easy fix.

First here are the Grub docs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2
Second here are the boot repair docs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another (brute force) option, if other methods fail, is to `apt download grub-pc` and manually extract the config files into the corresponding locations.